# Aligning checkbox and input text in same line for code given below

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to align the checkbox, label and text input in a same line using css. I can do it by using the default template of the browser.

However I really liked the simple theme given in this [link](http://cssdeck.com/labs/styling-labelled-form-input-text-field-with-css3). The theme has label and a input text. I wanted to add a checkbox as well at the beginning of the line. Somehow adding a checkbox inside the div makes the arrangement awry.

Though its better to look at the code in the link, I am providing a snapshot here:

**HTML**

```
<form>

    <div>
                <!--NEED TO ADD CHECKBOX HERE -->
        <label for="pub_url">Public URL</label>
        <input type="text" id="pub_url" name="pub_url" value="http://cssdeck.com">
    </div>

</form>
```

**CSS3**

```
/* Onto the styling now. Some quick generic styles first. */

html, body {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
}

body {
    font-size: 76%;
    font-family: Verdana;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 50px 0;
}

form {
    background: #fafafa;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #ffe2e3;
}

form div {
    /* Float containment */
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Things are looking good now, onto the main input field
styling now! */

/*
Lets change the box model to make the label and input
contain into the 100% div.

You might want to specify the box sizing properties inside
`* {}` at the top.

Things are looking great now! Lets just spice it up a bit.
*/
form label, form input {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

form label {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: linear-gradient(#f1f1f1, #e2e2e2);
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #444;

    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    /* lets remove the right border */
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;

    line-height: 1.5em;
    width: 30%;

    /* takes the width properly now and also the
    spacing between the label and input field got removed. */
    float: left;

    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* The label is looking good now. Onto the input field! */

/*
Everything is broken now! But we can fix it. Lets see how.
*/
form input {
    width: 70%;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;

    line-height: 1.5em;
    float: right;

    /* some box shadow sauce :D */
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px #ececec;
}
form input:focus {
    /* No outline on focus */
    outline: 0;
    /* a darker border ? */
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
}

/* Super! */
```

p.s: It will be delightful if someone can stylize the checkbox in the same way as the example

Comment: You want to use SO to outsource designing? You've not even provided an image of what you want to build nor is there any code to show that you at least tried.

Comment: no ofcourse not.. I tried to do by myself... I was not able to crack it

Comment: just add a float left to the checkbox and decrease the width of the input text to 60%.

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
form input[type="checkbox"] {
    width:20px;
}


<div>
    <input type="checkbox" >
    <label for="pub_url">Public URL</label>
    <input type="text" id="pub_url" name="pub_url" value="http://cssdeck.com">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KW6AY/1/

Answer (score 0):

just rename class

`form input`  into `form input[type="text"]`

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go \w quick styling:

http://codepen.io/daniesy/pen/puema

Answer (score 0):

alter the css to input[type="text"] and lower the width to around 60% (so it won't affect your checkbox), add a checkbox with a float left